# Repetitive cloud function only works on specific periods during the day

Tags: firebase, cron, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

my google cloud functions function should be repeated every 5 minutes.
It only works during specific periods of the day (without specifying that behavior in my settings).
This is the code triggered by the cron job:

```
exports.fivemins_job =
  functions.pubsub.topic('fivemins-tick').onPublish((event) => {
    console.log("This job is ran every 5 minutes!")

  });
```

**cron.yaml:**

```
cron:


- description: Push a "tick" onto pubsub every 5 minute
  url: /publish/fivemins-tick
  schedule: every 5 mins
```

**package.json:**

```
{
  "name": "functions",
  "description": "Cloud Functions for Firebase",
  "dependencies": {
    "@google-cloud/storage": "^0.4.0",
    "child-process-promise": "^2.2.0",
    "firebase-admin": "^4.1.2",
    "firebase-functions": "^0.5"
  },
  "private": true
}
```

**statistics:**
[image]

I would like to have it running all day and night. Any more info I should provide?

Comment: What does it mean to have a function "running all day and night"?

Comment: It has to check data every 5 minutes,  24 hours a day, 7 days a week

Comment: It looks like you've already got it set up that way, unless I'm missing something?

Comment: If I'm reading the graph correctly, it's only running a part of each day?

Comment: I found out that I reached my quota. Problem solved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I reached my quota. Found out after checking all the logs in the logbook and I found the following message:

```
severity:  "DEBUG"  
 textPayload:  "Billing account not configured. External network is not accessible and quotas are severely limited. Configure billing account to remove these restrictions"
```